# jquery active functions

Tags: jquery, function

How I can get an active functions list in jquery (or anything about active functions). I want to write code like this:

```
  if(anyfunction == false) { start another function}
```

I want start function if another function is stoped or stop this function if another function is started. But I have no idea how to do this using jquery. My real code is:

```
function slide(){
$("#slide1").addClass('inslide').fadeIn(ftime,function(){$("#slide1").delay(stime).fadeOut(ftime,function(){$("#slide1").removeClass("inslide"); $("#slide2").addClass('inslide').fadeIn(ftime,function(){$("#slide2").delay(stime).fadeOut(ftime,function(){$("#slide2").removeClass("inslide"); 
$("#slide3").addClass('inslide').fadeIn(ftime,function(){$("#slide3").delay(stime).fadeOut(ftime,function(){$("#slide3").removeClass("inslide"); $("#slide4").addClass('inslide').fadeIn(ftime,function(){$("#slide4").delay(stime).fadeOut(ftime,function(){$("#slide4").removeClass("inslide");
$("#slide5").addClass('inslide').fadeIn(ftime,function(){$("#slide5").delay(stime).fadeOut(ftime,function(){$("#slide5").removeClass("inslide"); slide()}) })  })  })  })  })  })  })  })  });
}
slide();

$("#back").click(function(){
var test = $(".inslide").attr("id");
var sub = test.substring(5);
sub = parseInt(sub);
var subin = sub - 1;
if(sub != 1) {
$("#slide"+sub).removeClass("inslide").fadeOut(ftime,function(){$("#slide"+subin+"").addClass('inslide').fadeIn(ftime)});
}
});
```

I want the `slide()` function to stop when the user clicks back.

Comment: if you are asking about mananging different animation queues deffered object methods can handle this - http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/